# How to handle multiple web service request at once

Tags: multithreading, web-services

I have developed web service in java (simple jax-ws). when my web service receives more than one request at a time i am getting DB lock exception in my-sql.

Can any one tell me how to execute the requests received in sequential order instead of parallel order

Comment: parallel threading is not the problem. Having a correct transactional system is what you should have a glance at (if you're concerned about dblocks)

Comment: Agreed with Sebas here you need to identify the cause of the DB lock and post details here. This is not a threading issue but a locking issue understanding the locking will identify the problem and then you can fix the problem vs guessing what it is.